# Stream won't work in webview

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm doing a project for school. I have to make an android app that gets the stream from an IP camera.

For this, I'm using [IP Webcam](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam) and I'm trying to get the stream from browser mode.

I made a html file with this code :`<img id="browser_video" class="video-image" alt="video" src="http://192.168.1.101:8080/video">` to get the stream from the camera and hosted it on my laptop for now. If I open it in Chrome on my laptop or on my tablet it works but if I open the file in a webview on the same tablet, I get a blank activity. This is my code from the activity :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    WebView webView;
    String URL = "http://192.168.1.187:8080/camera.html";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvPlayer);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl(URL);


    }

}
```

I do have permission for interned in my manifest but can't make it work...What to do?

Comment: Is it failing to load camera.html, or the <img /> inside? Can you add some extra markup into camera.html to see?

Comment: I don't really know what fails but I don't get any images on the app